# Как сохранить табуляцию в тексте, используя string.Format для вставки?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть код

```
var s1 = @"qwe
    asd
zxc";
var s2 = $@"123
    {s1}
456";
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Он выведет

```
123
    qwe
    asd
zxc
456
```

Это в общем то логично, но я хочу чтобы табуляция работала не только для первой строки, а для всего вставляемого блока.

Ожидаемый вывод

```
123
    qwe
        asd
    zxc
456
```

Comment: а ты уверен что у тебя там именно табуляция?

Comment: да же нет. А какой ожидаемый вывод?

Comment: Указывайте табуляцию в строковых константах явно через `\t` и не мучайтесь. В исходном тексте сделать замену реальных табов на служебную пару символов тоже не проблема.

Comment: @Grundy, да хоть табуляция, хоть пробелы. Я же вставляю блок и хочу чтобы форматировался он как блок.

Comment: @rdorn, вы готовый пример предложите ,я вас не понимаю. И не забудьте, что решение нужно универсальное, отступы могут быть разные (пробелы, табуляции и разное их количество).

Comment: А может быть, вам просто нужен шаблонизатор?

Comment: @VladD, во, только хотел тя позвать :) А настроить через какой-нибудь формат вывода нельзя?

Comment: @Grundy: Не-а, так на все случаи жизни форматов не напасёшься.